# Register custom ISpecimenBuilder only to a particular type

Tags: autofixture

I have a custom specimen builder for AutoFixture that omits requests for anonymous values in properties based on the type of the property being requested.

```cs
    public class PropertyTypeExclusion<T> : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            var propertyInfo = request as PropertyInfo;

            if (propertyInfo?.PropertyType == typeof(T))
            {
                return new OmitSpecimen();
            }

            return new NoSpecimen();
        }
    }
```

I can add the customization to the fixture no problem, and it works as expected.

`_fixture.Customizations.Add(new PropertyTypeExclusion<IdentityRef>());`

Now I want this exclusion to be registered to requests for a specific type. Something like this:

`_fixture.Customize<Release>(c => new PropertyTypeExclusion<IdentityRef>());`

While the use of `.Customize<Release>` is valid, it has the same outcome as the call to `.Customizations.Add`.

Is there a way to register this `ISpecimenBuilder` only to a specific requested type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to be able to do smth like this:

```
fixture.Create<Release>();       // the `IdentityRef` prop is omitted
fixture.Create<SomeOtherType>(); // the `IdentityRef` prop is NOT omitted
```

Ok, let's look on this statement:

> While the use of .Customize is valid, it has the same outcome as the call to .Customizations.Add

... meaning that even if you register the customization for the `Release` type only, the *other* types are impacted as well:

```
fixture.Customize<Release>(c => new PropertyTypeExclusion<IdentityRef>());
fixture.Create<Release>();       // the `IdentityRef` prop is omitted which is OK
fixture.Create<SomeOtherType>(); // the `IdentityRef` prop is also omitted but it MUST NOT
```

That sounds like a bug in AF to me and I'd address it [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues)...

As a quick workaround to your issue, you can extend the customization to accept *both* class and property types to perform more precise filtering:

```
public class PropertyTypeExclusion<TType, TProp> : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var propertyInfo = request as PropertyInfo;

        if (propertyInfo?.PropertyType == typeof(TProp) &&
            propertyInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(TType))
        {
            return new OmitSpecimen();
        }

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
}
```

Now:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(new PropertyTypeExclusion<Release, IdentityRef>());
fixture.Create<Release>();       // the `IdentityRef` prop is omitted
fixture.Create<SomeOtherType>(); // the `IdentityRef` prop is NOT omitted
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test this and see if it works. I didn't open a bug because I wasn't confident that the `_fixture.Customize<Release>(c => new Excluder())` was the appropriate syntax to accomplish what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

To fully re-use the existing AutoFixture's building blocks you could just create a specification:

```cs
public class PropertyOfTypeSpecification<TContainer, TProperty> : IRequestSpecification
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
    {
        return request is PropertyInfo propertyInfo
               && propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(TProperty)
               && propertyInfo.ReflectedType == typeof(TContainer);
    }
}
```

Later you could customize your Fixture as following:

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new Omitter(
        new PropertyOfTypeSpecification<Build, IdentityRef>()));
```

Comment: good answer because of the hook into using the `Omitter(` customization, however is it essentially the same as the accepted answer. I need to create a fixture-wide customization that is smart about the `DefiningType` or `ReflectedType` to make it work, where it would be more intuitive if `_f.Customize<TDefinintType>(c => new PropTypeOmitter())` would work as in my question.